Why is the Javascript file not loaded?
I am writing a simple log-in website with Javascript and HTML. The first page is "index.html". Here the user can log in with username and password. I just designed it.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login-Seite</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        button {
            width: 48%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 1%;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User name" required>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div>
            <button onclick="register()">Register</button>
            <button onclick="login()">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // Funktion für den Register-Button
        function register() {
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            alert(`Registrierung für Benutzer: ${username} mit Passwort: ${password}`);
            window.location.href = 'registrierung.html';
        }

        // Funktion für den Login-Button
        function login() {
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            alert(`Login für Benutzer: ${username} mit Passwort: ${password}`);
            // Hier kann weiterer Code hinzugefügt werden, um die Login-Überprüfung durchzuführen
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Here there are two textfields, one for the username and one for the password. So basically the login.
But this is not so important right now, I am now working at registering the user. So there is a button at index.html and the user is redirceted to "registrierung.html":
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login-Seite</title>
    <script src="index.js"  type="module" defer ></script>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        button {
            width: 48%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 1%;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User name" required>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="password" id="passwordR" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <div>
            <button id="submitButton" onclick="testFunction()">submit</button>
            <button id="backButton">Go back to Login</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        /* import { createUser } from 'index.js';

         
        
        // Funktion für den Register-Button
        document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function submit() {
            
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            alert(`Registrierung für Benutzer: ${username} mit Passwort: ${password}`);
            createUser(email, password);
            // Hier kann weiterer Code hinzugefügt werden, um die Registrierung durchzuführen
        }*/

        // Funktion für den Login-Button
        /*document.getElementById("backButton").onclick =function goback() {
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            alert(`Login für Benutzer: ${username} mit Passwort: ${password}`);
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
            // Hier kann weiterer Code hinzugefügt werden, um die Login-Überprüfung durchzuführen
        }*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>

So as you see, in "registrierung.html" the user can type a username, a password, repeat it and his email. When the button submit is pressed, then the user should be signed in at firebase. This is how "registrierung.html" should work.
But for testing, I have only programmed one thing, that is carried out, wenn the button submit is pressed: A test function from "index.js" should be carried out.
This is "index.js":
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "..."
  authDomain: "..."
  projectId: "..."
  storageBucket: "..."
  messagingSenderId: "..."
  appId: "..."
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth();
function createUser(email, password){
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed up 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });

}

function testFunction(){
    const a = 1+1;
}



signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });



So just look at the testFunction where a simple operation is done.
The problem is now, that, eventhough I included index.js in registrierung.html, index.js is not loaded, when I run it on my local server.
Even though when I use logs, they are not shown in the console.
I am working with Visual Studio Code and I am using Live Server which is running on http://127.0.0.1:5500/

Do you see error messages in the browser console?


defer in type="module" is redundant, not your issue. 2. functions declared in a type="module" script are not in the global scope - this may be your issue


This is my Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick .

I recommend Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice? It solves your problem.

Define your testFunction like this in the index.js file:
(top ?? window).testFunction = () =>
{
   window.alert('The test worked!');
}

This way your function will be available at the top context (or window which is the direct context the document that loaded index.js) and will work at any place in your document.

This is my Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
